# How to use google vertex OCR

Tags: ocr, google-vision

I was using google vision for OCR. but there is an offical announcement for Vision Deprecation so there is an vertex AI available. In that they mentioned a pre trained model for vetex OCR now to use that I need an endpoint.

In offical docs **https://cloud.google.com/distributed-cloud/hosted/docs/latest/gdch/platform/pa-user/iam/sign-in**
they told process to use it but they mentioned *https://GDCH_URL*.
I don't know what is **GDCH_URL** where and how I will get it.

How can I get **GDCH_URL** ?

Answer (score 0):

Vision API is in active development. The most recent model upgrades were December 5, 2023 which became the default models in March 2024. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes . You can continue using it.

AutoML Vision is a different product that was moved to Vertex https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/deprecations